# WebBrowser PDF set focus

Tags: vba, pdf

I would like to change the focus TextBox <-> PDF-WebBrowser. Both elements are in a user form, and basically i want to copy the text from the TextBox and search it on the PDF, but for that i need to change the focus between the elements.

I use the next two functions, 1st for display the PDF and 2nd for search the text into the text:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
        Me.WebBrowser1.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""E:\Test.pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
    End Sub

    Private Sub find_pdf()
        Me![WebBrowser1].SetFocus   'Set Focus to the Web Browser Control (WebBrowser1)
        SendKeys "^f", True         'CTRL+F will place Cursor in Find Box
        SendKeys text_to_find       'txtFind: String with the text to find
        SendKeys "{ENTER}"          'Simulate pressing the ENTER Key
    End Sub
```

In resume, i would like to jump the focus from TextBox to PDF and from PDF to Textbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So is your code not working?  Can you simply SetFocus() back to the original textbox after sending the simulated {Enter} keypress? Or if you're trying to jump into the actual PDF document, how about sending the {Tab} key?

Comment: The "SetFocus" function from the TextBox doesn't work, and the "SetFocus" from the WebBrowser doesn't point to the PDF, it's only focusing the WebBrowser itself but not the PDF, in fact, the SendKeys commands don't work either unless i do "click" on the PDF.

Comment: I've been able to start the focus on the textbox inserting a timer, when it triggers it brings back the focus to the form. Next step is how to move it again to PDF WebBrowser.